# Platform-specific variables for Linux i install4j

Tags: linux, variables, redhat, install4j

I am trying to build an application in Linux but the application directory used for the windows version (sys.ProgramDataDir) is platform-specific. Is there an equivalent installer variable that I could define for RedHat?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is installed in `/opt/app`, then I would recommend `/var/opt/app` for the dynamic data.